# Can't access conda packages from python

Tags: python, matplotlib, anaconda, pyenv

I've used anaconda to install managed matplotlib using `conda install matplotlib`

but when I start python, it says it can't find matplotlib

if I use pip install, it finds matplotlib, but complains about being a non framework version

How can I used anaconda's matplotlib in python?

If I uninstall and reinstall the anaconda version, everything is fine.

THis seems to have been triggered by an execution of `pip install -r requirements.txt` that yielded the installation of a different matplotlib, but the problem persisted even after uninstalling the different version

Comment: what operating system? what's the output of `which python`?

Comment: on OSX `/usr/local/var/pyenv/versions/anaconda3-2.5.0/bin/python`

Comment: That doesn't look right.  My anaconda paths look like this: `/Users/7stud/anaconda/bin/`

Comment: yeah, I'm sure I did something crazy at some point with path management, but the point is that python is genuinely pointing to the conda3-2.5 version

Comment: I"m also using pyenv, and not the direct install

Comment: what is the output of `conda info --envs` ? I'm betting that conda has installed matplotlib somewhere else..